# In VS Code, how can I go to to the text which is highlighted in grey color

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, highlight

In the image below the text "Document" which is written in "<title "is highlighted in grey color.
Is there any way I can go there with any shortcut or something like that?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

These are called [snippet "tabstops" or "placeholders"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_tabstops).